# Библиотечный класс и java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть класс, который используется во многих проектах. (Android, Java SE, Java EE). Класс отвечает за коммуникацию с сервером.

Все проекты компилируются с уровнем языка 1.8, а вот андроид с таким уровнем работать не может, поэтому он 1.7. Следовательно и библиочетный класс компилируется с уровнем 1.7.

Так вот, когда я подключаю библиотечный класс к ВЕБ приложению(к сервису), я получаю ошибку

```
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
```

Если я скопирую класс в папку проекта - все работает.

Иду дальше. между Веб приложением и главной библиотекой есть промежуточная библиотека. Она компилируется с уровнем 1.8. Если скопировать туда и подключить к веб приложению - все работает.

Так это что получается, все из за разных уровней языка? использовать общую библиотеку одну на всех не получится?

PS другие классы из главной библиотеки подключаются и работают как надо. Вот только с CommunicationClass проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, тут что-то другое, т.к. ява довольно хорошо обратно совместима. Иначе весь мавен централ надо бы было под 1.8 пересобирать. У нас в нексусе тьма под еще 1.6 скомпелировано и отлично все работает и под 7 и под 8.

Сомтрите на зависимости самой библиотеки. Скорей всего, там есть какая-то часть, которая уникальна и зависит от окружения.

[**Декомпилируйте байткод**](http://jd.benow.ca/) вашей библиотеки и посмотрите, чего в ней не хватает. Там может быть оптимизатор выкидывает какой нибудь метод приватный, который не используется на прямую, а вы его потом с помощью рефлексии вытягиваете (этим часто самописные ОРМ фреймворки страдают)